# How to prevent child objects to move ?

Tags: parent

I have created a light bulb and I want all the objects of the light bulb "behave as one entity". So I thought I should create an empty and make that empty the parent of all child objects (together the light bulb). But now it is still possible to select and move an individual child object. And I don't want that. If I select the glass and move that I want the whole light bulb to move.

I want to build a library of 3D models and I want to be able to append a 3D model (for instance a light bulb) and move that model in my scene. But I do't want to join all meshes, I want the individual child objects to stay separate objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly what [*Dupli Groups*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupligroup.html) are for.

1. Create a group that includes all the individual components.
2. Add this group as an instance into the scene: Add > Group Instance. This instance will behave like one object.
3. You can link a group from another file, which could represent that library you want to create. In the library file you have still access to all the groups components and you can edit them, but the linked instance will behave like one entity.

This has also other benefits like saving memory if you need multiple instances of the same group.

Comment: Ah yes, this is a much better answer than mine. Do this.

Comment: But will this not allow grabbing parts of this group individually?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable select for the child objects by clicking on the cursor icon next to their name in the outliner (top right panel). The icon should then gray out. You would then be unable to select those objects in the 3D view. Only the parent object would be selectable and movable. The only way to then move the child objects would be to explicitly select them in the outliner.

As an alternative, you **may** be able to apply a constraint to each of the child objects to prevent them moving in local space, however, I am unsure if this is actually possible. In any event, it would be overly complicated for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways, first one is to select all the lightbulb parts then join them using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, this is not ideal.

The second solution which is better, is to add a apply Location for each part of the separate lightbulb meshes using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then choose `Location` then add a limit distance constraint to each part of the light bulb except for the base part of the lightbulb, then set the target to the base part of the lightbulb base.

[image]

As shown here the Torus won't be able to move except when the cube moves.